# How to create a table on Azure Synapse using C# client?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-synapse

I need to create a table on Azure Synapse (schema and other details less important at the moment).

I found [`SynapseManagementClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.synapse.synapsemanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet), but besides getting a client (`var client = new SynapseManagementClient(new Uri(synapseUri), credentials);`), I didn't find any working example.

Any idea how to create a table on Azure Synapse with C#?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the Azure Synapse in azure portal.
2. Create SQL Pool.
3. Set the firewall settings to allow azure services and resources to access the workspace, else you will be getting forbidden error.

[image]

I have used the below code and able to create table in **Azure synapse**.

```
   string apiUrl = "Azure Synapse Workspace URL";
   string apiKey = "API Key";
   string createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE testTable (id int, name string)";
   string sqlQuery = $"{createTableStatement};";
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("spark-api-key", apiKey);
            var content = new StringContent(sqlQuery, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content).Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Console.WriteLine("Table created successfully!");
       }
```

Table created successfully using the client in **Azure Synapse**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! do you know where do I find the API key?

Comment: 1. Login to the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com)
2. Go to the Azure Synapse workspace that you want to access.
3. Click on "Shared credentials" in the navigation panel on the left.
4. Click on "New/Update API Key" and enter a name for your API key and select its expiration date, then click on "Create" Your API key will be generated and displayed.